# Duplicated subtitles issue in Internet Explorer with the video player (plyr.io)

Tags: javascript, duplicates, html5-video, closed-captions, plyr.js

I am using https://plyr.io/ to have a video player with captions. (Documentation: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr).

I call the polyfilled plyr library (https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.polyfilled.js) via the CDN for the moment (Currently I am only on a test phase, once everything works fine I will use the files system, not the CDN).

The problem is that on Internet Explorer (IE11) I get double captions. See below:

[image]

The issue appears only on this IE browser. On other browsers I only have the captions with the blue background which is good (I guess they are generated by JavaScript via the WebVTT file).

I don't want the native ones (in white and without background).

So how to delete these unwanted captions to only have the customized ones?

Ps: English captions are set by default in my code, and when I select another language such as French which is not the default language, the captions with blue background disappears, only the white captions are displayed which is not good.

See below:

[image]

Additionally I noticed a JS error in the console only for IE that says: "unexpected call to method or property access". See below:

[image]

Any idea?

Is it something to tell to the developer of https://plyr.io/ or is it only on my side?

PPS: I also think it is related to the "polyfilled" script that I call in the  of my HTML document. Maybe there is something to set here.

Thank you.

```js
// Here I initialize the "plyr" with its options (You can set debug to true if you want)
const player = new Plyr('#player', {
  captions: {
    active: true,
    update: false,
    language: 'en'
  },
  debug: false
});

// var video = document.getElementById('player');
// player.config.captions.active = false;
// video.textTracks[0].mode = "showing";
// console.log('video.textTracks[0].mode = ' + video.textTracks[0].mode);
// console.log('player.config.captions.active = ' + player.config.captions.active);


// This is only to display captions for the demo, the issue is not there
function parse_timestamp(s) {
  var match = s.match(/^(?:([0-9]{2,}):)?([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9][.,][0-9]{0,3})/);
  if (match == null) {
    throw 'Invalid timestamp format: ' + s;
  }
  var hours = parseInt(match[1] || "0", 10);
  var minutes = parseInt(match[2], 10);
  var seconds = parseFloat(match[3].replace(',', '.'));
  return seconds + 60 * minutes + 60 * 60 * hours;
}

// https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Video_Text_Tracks_Format
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebVTT
//
// For better parsers, look at:
// https://github.com/annevk/webvtt
// https://github.com/mozilla/vtt.js
function quick_and_dirty_vtt_or_srt_parser(vtt) {
  var lines = vtt.trim().replace('\r\n', '\n').split(/[\r\n]/).map(function(line) {
    return line.trim();
  });
  var cues = [];
  var start = null;
  var end = null;
  var payload = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].indexOf('-->') >= 0) {
      var splitted = lines[i].split(/[ \t]+-->[ \t]+/);
      if (splitted.length != 2) {
        throw 'Error when splitting "-->": ' + lines[i];
      }

      // Already ignoring anything past the "end" timestamp (i.e. cue settings).
      start = parse_timestamp(splitted[0]);
      end = parse_timestamp(splitted[1]);
    } else if (lines[i] == '') {
      if (start && end) {
        var cue = new VTTCue(start, end, payload);
        cues.push(cue);
        start = null;
        end = null;
        payload = null;
      }
    } else if (start && end) {
      if (payload == null) {
        payload = lines[i];
      } else {
        payload += '\n' + lines[i];
      }
    }
  }

  return cues;
}

function init() {
  // http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/
  // https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2015/02/javascript/dynamically-adding-text-tracks-to-html5-video
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  var subtitles = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  Array.prototype.slice.call(subtitles)
    .filter(node => node.type === "text/vtt")
    .map((subtitle, index) => {
      var track = video.addTextTrack('subtitles', subtitle.dataset.label, subtitle.dataset.lang);
      var first_sub = index == 0 ? "showing" : "hidden";
      track.mode = first_sub;
      quick_and_dirty_vtt_or_srt_parser(subtitle.innerHTML).map(function(cue) {
        track.addCue(cue);
      });
    });
}
init();
```

```css
#container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.plyr__captions .plyr__caption {
  background: #0066a1 !important;
  font-family: Cambria;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.polyfilled.js"></script>

<div id="container">

  <video controls crossorigin playsinline poster="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/images/BigBuckBunny.jpg" id="player" class="img-responsive">

    <!-- Video file -->
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    <!-- Caption files -->
    <!--
    <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="my-en-subtitles.vtt" crossorigin default>
    <track label="Portuguese" kind="subtitles" srclang="pt" src="my-pt-subtitles.vtt" crossorigin>
    -->

    <script type="text/vtt" id="subtitle" data-label="English" data-lang="en">
      WEBVTT

      1
      00:00:02.500 --> 00:00:05.250
      WebVTT directly embeded

      2
      00:00:05.250 --> 00:00:09.750
      inside a script tag

      3
      00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:13.000
      for the demo.

      4
      00:00:14.000 --> 00:00:17.000
      Test
      
      5
      00:00:18.000 --> 00:00:20.000
      ...
      
      6
      00:00:21.000 --> 00:00:22.000
      ...

    </script>
    
    <script type="text/vtt" id="subtitle-2" data-label="French" data-lang="fr">
      WEBVTT

      1
      00:00:02.500 --> 00:00:05.250
      WebVTT directement inséré

      2
      00:00:05.250 --> 00:00:09.750
      dans un script

      3
      00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:13.000
      pour la demonstration.

      4
      00:00:14.000 --> 00:00:17.000
      Test
      
      5
      00:00:18.000 --> 00:00:20.000
      ...
      
      6
      00:00:21.000 --> 00:00:22.000
      ...

    </script>


    <p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the HTML5 video element.</p>

  </video>

</div>
```

Comment: can you supply a minimal verifiable sample to demonstrate the problem - hard to determine where the issue is with only a picture of the result

Comment: I agree. But for me it is also hard to provide you the same environment in stackoverflow to replicate the issue. In my own environment, WebVTT are in separated files and called with the classic way via the html5 <track> tag, whereas here I call it directly via a script. My WebVTT files are online but only accessible under my company credentials portal. When I try to use other online subtitles, I get a cross-origin error, so my subtitles are not shown. Sorry I am novice here, can you help me to provide you something testable?

Comment: It is hard to replicate the error as IE doesn't display the video player but it uses the native one from IE instead. So I doubt my code snippet is relevant. I improved a bit the description of the issue with the polyfilled.js file + a screenshot of the JS error in the IE console. I hope it gives you more information to help me...

Comment: I finally found out from where was coming the issue, I use other JavaScript libraries and they make conflicts with plyr.js. For those who are curious the conflict was because of "magnific-popup.js" which was used in my template to display the video in a popup. I removed this feature so I don't have this issue. Thank you @Offbeatmammal for your response.